# таймер обратного отсчёта до конца текущих суток

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как написать  чтобы получится таймер обратного отсчёта до конца текущих суток...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так, если нужны сутки по UTC:

```js
function update() {
  var dt = Date.now()
  var now = Math.floor(dt / 1000)
  var next = Math.ceil(dt / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) * 60 * 60 * 24
  var left = next - now
  var text = ~~(left/60/60) + "h " + ~~(left/60%60) + "m " + ~~(left%60) + "s"
  document.body.textContent = text
}

update()
setInterval(update, 1000)
```

Если надо по местному времени, то так:

```js
function update() {
  var dt = new Date
  var tz = dt.getTimezoneOffset()
  var now = Math.floor(dt / 1000 - tz * 60)
  var next = Math.ceil((dt / 1000 / 60 - tz) / 60 / 24) * 60 * 60 * 24
  var left = next - now
  var text = ~~(left/60/60) + "h " + ~~(left/60%60) + "m " + ~~(left%60) + "s"
  document.body.textContent = text
}

update()
setInterval(update, 1000)
```

Comment: Спасибо, а почему нету html?

Comment: А зачем? Таймер же и так работает))

Comment: очень нужно стилизовать

Comment: ну так стилизуй, кто ж запрещает?

Comment: вопрос состоит как. где теги которые ты создал???

Comment: так я ж не создавал - создай сам, какие там тебе нужны